# Creating a dictionary of word count of multiple text files in a directory

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using build_dict() function in word_count_directory() function  to create  a dictionary of word counts of  three files in a directory. I want to create three dictionaries (one at a time  for each file) and update previous dictionary.  My code creates a single dictionary (word_count) that combining  all three dictionaries at same time. I was wondering how to accomplish this?

```
def build_dict(filename):
   f = open(filename, 'rU')
   words = f.read().split()
   count = {}

   for word in words:
      word = word.lower()
      if word not in count:
        count[word] = 1
      else:
        count[word] += 1

   f.close()

   return count
## print build_dict("C:\\Users\\Phil2040\\Desktop\\word_count\\news1.txt")

import os
import os.path
def word_count_directory(directory):
    wordcount={}
    filelist=[os.path.join(directory,f) for f in os.listdir(directory)]
    for file in filelist:
       wordcount=build_dict(file)  # calling build_dict function
    return wordcount
print word_count_directory("C:\\Users\\Phil2040\\Desktop\\Word_count")
```

Comment: Are you sure your code combines all three dictionaries? Looking at it, I would guess that the dict would only contain the values from the last file.

Comment: @ Kevin.  I am anticipating that but not quite sure.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Example files:

`/tmp/foo.txt`

```
hello world
hello world
foo bar
foo bar baz
```

`/tmp/bar.txt`

```
hello world
hello world
foo bar
foo bar baz
foo foo foo
```

You can create one `Counter` per file, then add them together!

```
from collections import Counter

def word_count(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        c = Counter()
        for line in f:
            c.update(line.strip().split(' '))
        return c

files = ['/tmp/foo.txt', '/tmp/bar.txt']
counters = [word_count(filename) for filename in files]

# counters content (example):
# [Counter({'world': 2, 'foo': 2, 'bar': 2, 'hello': 2, 'baz': 1}),
#  Counter({'foo': 5, 'world': 2, 'bar': 2, 'hello': 2, 'baz': 1})]

# Add all the word counts together:
total = sum(counters, Counter())  # sum needs an empty counter to start with

# total content (example):
# Counter({'foo': 7, 'world': 4, 'bar': 4, 'hello': 4, 'baz': 2})
```

Comment: @ Andre`Laszlo. Thanks for great answer.  I am, however, sticking to use of function.

Comment: Excellent answer, most pythonic solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
def word_count_directory(directory):
    filelist=[os.path.join(directory,f) for f in os.listdir(directory)]
    return [build_dict(file) for file in filelist]
```

This will return a list of dictionary, one for each of your file.

If you want to get the wordcount of each file one after the other you can use a yield :

```
def word_count_directory(directory):
    filelist=[os.path.join(directory,f) for f in os.listdir(directory)]
    for file in filelist:
        yield build_dict(file)

word_count_directory(".") # gets the wordcount of the first file
word_count_directory(".") #   .         .       . the second file
```

For your first function you should take a look at the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class from the collections module.

Comment: @ volent . Thanks for answer. My idea is to update wordcount {} dictionary with successive three dictionaries (probably using update method of dictionary).

Comment: You mean that for each call you want to get the wordcount dictionary of the next file ? I updated my answer with an example of what I understood.

Comment: @ volent I mean at first call first dictionary is created that fills up empty wordcount{} and second call second dictionary is created (this updates first dictionary) and so on.

Comment: Yes then my update is what you want. (the version with yield)

Comment: @ volent wouldn't it give word count for each file? I wan to create a single wordcount{} dictionary from three dictionary created (using function) and  updating each other successively.

Comment: Thanks volent. I am manually updating values in dictionaries.