# How to get "aggregate" word count from pandas Series elements

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, data-science, word-count

I'm currently using python3.7 in a Jupyter Notebook (v5.6.0) with pandas 0.23.4.

I've written code to tokenize some Japanese words and have successfully applied a word count function that returns the word counts from each row in a pandas Series like so:

```
0       [(かげ, 20), (モリア, 17), (たち, 15), (お前, 14), (おれ,...
1       [(お前, 11), (ゾロ, 10), (うっ, 10), (たち, 9), (サンジ, ...
2       [(おれ, 11), (男, 6), (てめえ, 6), (お前, 5), (首, 5), ...
3       [(おれ, 19), (たち, 14), (ヨホホホ, 12), (お前, 10), (みん...
4       [(ラブーン, 32), (たち, 14), (おれ, 12), (お前, 12), (船長...
5       [(ヨホホホ, 19), (おれ, 13), (ラブーン, 12), (船長, 11), (...
6       [(わたし, 20), (おれ, 16), (海賊, 9), (お前, 9), (もう, 9...
7       [(たち, 21), (あたし, 15), (宝石, 14), (おれ, 12), (ハッ,...
8       [(おれ, 13), (あれ, 9), (もう, 7), (ヨホホホ, 7), (見え, 7...
9       [(ケイミー, 23), (人魚, 20), (はっち, 14), (おれ, 13), (め...
10      [(ケイミー, 18), (おれ, 17), (め, 14), (たち, 12), (はっち...
```

From this previously asked question:

[Creating a dictionary of word count of multiple text files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28153549/creating-a-dictionary-of-word-count-of-multiple-text-files-in-a-directory)

I thought I could use the answer to help with my objective.

I want to consolidate all the above pairs in each row into a dictionary where the key is the Japanese text, and the value is the sum of all the instances of the text appearing within the data set. I thought I could accomplish this with the `collections.Counter` module by turning each row in the series into a dictionary, like this:

```
vocab_list = []
for i in range(len(wordcount)):
    vocab_list.append(dict(wordcount[i]))
```

Which gives me the dictionary format that I want, where each row in the Series is now a dictionary, like so:

```
[{'かげ': 20,
 'モリア': 17,
 'たち': 15,
 'お前': 14,
 'おれ': 11,
 'もう': 9,
 '船長': 7,
 'っ': 7,
 '七武海': 7,
 '言っ': 6, ...
```

My problem comes when I try to use the `sum()` function and `Counter()` to aggregate the totals:

```
vocab_list = sum(vocab_list, Counter())
print(vocab_list)
```

Instead of getting the expected "aggregated dictionary", I receive the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-3c66e97f4559> in <module>()
      3     vocab_list.append(dict(wordcount[i]))
      4 
----> 5 vocab_list = sum(vocab_list, Counter())
      6 vocab_list

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Counter' and 'dict'
```

Could you explain what exactly is wrong in the code and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the elements in your series are of type `Counter` you can simply aggregate by `sum`

```
df.agg(sum)
```

Example:

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.Series([[('かげ', 20), ('男', 17), ('たち', 15), ('お前', 14)],[('お前', 11), ('ゾロ', 10), ('うっ', 10), ('たち', 9)],[('おれ', 11), ('男', 6), ('てめえ', 6), ('お前', 5), ('首', 5)]])   
df = df.apply(lambda x: Counter({y[0]:y[1] for y in x}))

df
# Out:
# 0          {'かげ': 20, '男': 17, 'たち': 15, 'お前': 14}
# 1          {'お前': 11, 'ゾロ': 10, 'うっ': 10, 'たち': 9}
# 2    {'おれ': 11, '男': 6, 'てめえ': 6, 'お前': 5, '首': 5}
# dtype: object

df.agg(sum)
# Out:
# Counter({'うっ': 10,
#          'おれ': 11,
#          'お前': 30,
#          'かげ': 20,
#          'たち': 24,
#          'てめえ': 6,
#          'ゾロ': 10,
#          '男': 23,
#          '首': 5})
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I can append `most_common()` to the end of the `agg()` function to show the values in descending order, I assume?

Comment: Never mind. That method would have taken way too long with the size of my data. Converting the list to a pandas dataframe, then sorting by descending order along the count column did the trick! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I am unframiliar with Counter(), but I think it may have to do with the fact that your dictionary is inside a list.

Also, you could do this quite easliy without the use of additional tool (like counter). Here is something I threw together that 'works' but may not be performat in your use case:

```
vocab_list = [{'かげ': 20,
            'モリア': 17,
            'たち': 15,
            'お前': 14,
            'おれ': 11,
            'もう': 9,
            '船長': 7}]

numberz = list(vocab_list[0].values())
totalz = 0
for x in numberz:
    totalz += x

print(totalz)

Out [29]: 93
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The aim is to take the total of each word throughout the dataset, so for example, かげ will appear many times in each row of the data set. So, the total number of times each word appears, i.e.:

    [{'かげ': 2000,
      'モリア': 1700,
      'たち': 1500,
      'お前': 1400,
      'おれ': 1100,
      'もう': 900,
      '船長': 700}]