# Python3 - For loop access array value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below Python script, counts the number of words in a text file:

```
from collections import Counter

def main():
    with open(TEXT_FILE) as f:
        wordscounts = Counter(f.read().split())
        print(wordscounts)
```

Above gives me:

```
Counter({'invoice': 10, 'USD': 8, 'order': 5})
```

Now I want to add these words to another text file `dictionary.txt`, like:

```
invoice 10
USD 8
order 5
```

And next time I process a file, and check for word frequency, for example:

```
 Counter({'invoice': 2, 'USD': 1, 'tracking': 3})
```

It should add the count to the words already in the file, and append the new.

So `dictionary.txt` becomes:

```
invoice 12
USD 9
order 5
tracking 3
```

If I try to iterate through the `wordscount`, I only get the actual word:

```
 for index, wordcount in enumerate(wordscounts):
     print(wordcount)
```

gives me:

```
invoice
USD
order
```

But not the word count.

Comment: There are some missing steps that make it not clear what you mean by `wordscounts` - for example, is it a Counter object? if so then you are iterating through the object incorrectly. Also, if you are iterating a dictionary then you are also incorrectly looping.

Comment: I have added `from collections import Counter` to my quesiton. Can you elaborate on why I am looping incorrectly?

Comment: I see that you did clarify what the `wordscounts` was. But, the enumerate wordscounts does not give you the values for the counters. It is the same principle of looping a dict for keys and values. The answer below shows how one can do it.

Comment: A Counter is a dict subclass so you can use dictionary methods like `for word, wordcount in wordscounts.items():`

Comment: You may want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28153549/creating-a-dictionary-of-word-count-of-multiple-text-files-in-a-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the Counter dictionary. Small example

```py
from collections import Counter
wordcount_1 = Counter("an example test test test".split())
wordcount_2 = Counter("another example test".split())

for word in wordcount_1:
    print(word, wordcount_1[word])
# example 1
# test 3
# an 1
```

If you want to build the sum (in memory) (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28153640)), use

```py
total = sum([wordcount_1, word_count_2], Counter())
```

Comment: Ah, this works perfectly! Do you have any idea regarding the last part of my question? Adding the words to another file - but only updating the word count if the word already exists.

Comment: If possible, have the full word counter in memory and save afterwards. If that's not possible because of the size of your problem, I would sort the save by the words, which will fasten your search (and check if something is new).

Comment: Would you mind giving a simple example of this? I am brand new to Python, so still learning.

Comment: Added the easier in memory variant, which I would try first

Answer (score 1):

You can get the actual wordcount using:

```
for index, wordcount in enumerate(wordscounts):
     print(wordscounts[wordcount])
```

Printing `wordcount` only gives you the key, while printing `wordcounts[wordcount]` gives you the value.